# Fatou's Lemma for non-negative random variables

Tags: probability-theory

I've seen the following statement online (without an explanation):
If $ (X_n)_n $ is a sequence of non-negative random variables, then $ \limsup_{n\to\infty}X_{n} $ is also a random variable, and the following holds:

$ \limsup_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}[X_{n}]\leq\mathbb{E}[\limsup_{n\to\infty}X_{n}] $.

The only Fatou's Lemma Im familier with is Fatou's Lemma for events, that is, if $ (A_n)_n $ is a sequence of events, we have:

$ \mathbb{P}\left(\liminf_{n}A_{n}\right)\leq\liminf_{n}\mathbb{P}\left(A_{n}\right)\leq\limsup_{n}\mathbb{P}\left(A_{n}\right)\leq\mathbb{P}\left(\limsup_{n}A_{n}\right) $

But more importent, I cant see why the first inequallity I mentioned holds. I can find a counter example;

Consider $ U $ a uniformly distributed random variable over $ [0,1]$ , that is, $ U\sim U[0,1] $

And define
$ X_{n}\left(\omega\right)=\begin{cases}
n^{2}1_{\left\{ U<\frac{1}{n}\right\} } & U\left(\omega\right)\neq0\\
0 & U\left(\omega\right)=0
\end{cases} $

and  $ Z_{n}=n^{2}1_{\left\{ U<\frac{1}{n}\right\} } $

Since $ Z_n-X_n$ is a non-negative random variable, and $ \mathbb{P}\left(Z_{n}-X_{n}=0\right)=1 $, we have that for any $ n $ $ \mathbb{E}[Z_{n}]=\mathbb{E}[X_{n}] $.

But, $ \limsup X_{n}\equiv0 $ and thus $ \mathbb{E}[\limsup X_{n}]=0 $, and on the other hand

$ \mathbb{E}[Z_{n}]=n\mathbb{E}[1_{\{U<\frac{1}{n}\}}]=n^{2}\mathbb{P}[U<\frac{1}{n}]=\frac{n^{2}}{n}=n $

So $ \limsup_{n}\mathbb{E}[X_{n}]=\limsup_{n}\mathbb{E}[Z_{n}]=\infty $.

Can someone tell if the first inequallity I mentioned is wrong or if the counterexample I have is wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: while I'm not very knowledgeable in the language of probability, the first inequality you wrote is what I've sometimes heard as the [reverse Fatou's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatou%27s_lemma#Reverse_Fatou_lemma), and for it one needs an extra hypothesis, namely that there is a dominating integrable function.

Comment: Im not familier with the term "dominating integrable function", can you elaborate?

Comment: The inequality is true for **non-positive** random variables and random variables dominated by an integrable random variable and is false in general for non-negative random variables.